# Datetime and Sqllite problem in between two numbers

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, datetime

my code is :

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO url(email, product, date) VALUES("email@email.com","0", "2020-04-05")',)
sqlite_select_query = "SELECT date FROM 'url' "
cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
print(records[0])
date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"
a = records
b = datetime.date.today()
delta = b - a
print(delta.days)
connection.commit()
```

The error that returns is:

```
delta = b - a
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'tuple'
```

What should i do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you do

```
a = records
```

a is a tuple, not the value of date from the records.

So records is a tuple of tuples.

So what you need is to simply do

```
result = records[0]
a = result["date"]
```

Or you could do

```
records = cursor.fetchone()
a = records["date"]
```

Comment: delta = b - a
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'tuple'